# How to make a stepcounter working in the background?

Tags: java, android

I have an app which is supposed to count footsteps via my smartphone, it is working just fine. However, I would like it to be able to count steps while I'm not using it in the background.

This is my code, it is written in polish, for that I'm sorry. Here are few translations.

```
mLiczKrok is Footsteps count
textKroki is a text View which means TextFootsteps
```

**What should I add in on pause method,in order to continue counting?**

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
        //ask for permission
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION}, PHYISCAL_ACTIVITY);
    }
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    textKroki= findViewById(R.id.textKroki);
    sensorManager= (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)!=null){

        mLiczKrok = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        x= true;
    }
    else {

        textKroki.setText("Brak sensora."); x=false;
    }
}



 @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
if (sensorEvent.sensor==mLiczKrok){
LiczKroki= (int) sensorEvent.values[0];
textKroki.setText(String.valueOf(LiczKroki));}}
 @Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)!=null){

      sensorManager.registerListener(this,mLiczKrok,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)!=null){
      sensorManager.unregisterListener(this,mLiczKrok);

    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that on pause method having unregistering type_step_counter sensor. Which will never recieves the foot step counting  Please remove following lines present in onpause method. And re-run and test your app.

```
    if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor( 
                  Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) != null){
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mLiczKrok);
     }
```

Add above lines inside ondestroy() of activity.

Note: if this context Is not suitable to you, please inform. In you project is there any reason behind unregistering foot step counter sensor in onpause method .??

Comment: it is working,although I do not know whether it will work or not when some other app starts working,e.g. somebody calls me. Shouldn't the app stop l counting?